# Invalid Date format from Database

Tags: force.com, java, date

Trying to insert a Contact from an Oracle Database:

Contact Database Entity:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="DOB")
private Date dob;
```

Contact SOAP SObject set Birthday:

```
Calendar dobCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
dobCalendar.setTime(dwContact.getDob());
contact.setField("Birthdate", dobCalendar);
```

Error Message:

> ERROR CODE: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION MESSAGE: Birthdate: invalid
>   date: Fri Nov 30 00:00:00 GMT 3

Any suggestions?

Comment: what soap stack ore you using?

Comment: Partner Connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Salesforce SOAP API guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/apex_api.pdf) setField takes a Java Calendar object.

The following is using v29 of the WSC Partner API.

```
    com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject record = new SObject();
    record.setType("Test__c");
    record.setField("Date__c", Calendar.getInstance());
    record.setField("NewDate__c", Calendar.getInstance());
    SaveResult[] result = connection.create(new SObject[] { record });
```

The following results in the following for me

[image]

The above two fields are defined as Date and DateTime as follows...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are passing in the wrong date format.  If you run the below code in an execute anonymous window you will see the format that SF is expecting

```
Contact c = [Select Id, Birthdate From Contact Where Birthdate != null limit 1];
system.debug('Date Format Example: ' + c.Birthdate);
```

**OUTPUT**

> 13:09:36.051 (51068646)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Date Format Example:
>   **1946-03-19 00:00:00**

You need to try to adjust your date format prior to trying to set the Birthdate field